# Running spot Instance automatically replaces, even when it was not configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip, spot-instances

I was recently using a spot instance for testing my Node application. We were using it's Public IPv4 DNS to communicate with the node server running on it. However, I recently noticed I was not able to access it anymore because it's IPv4 and DNS had changed and my application had stopped running.

Questions

1. I had set no such parameters when requesting for the Spot Instance, to replace in case of Interruption. How did my instance get automatically replaced with a working one?
2. I'm amusing the instance was replaced when Interrupted because my public IPv4 and DNS had changed and my application stopped working (although it was still available on the system as it was using the same EBS). I hope I'm correct in this case.
3. Does a spot instance change their IPv4 and DNS in anyway without replacing the running instance? (I'm not sure it does, still, I'm confused).
4. Considering the spot instance was interrupted and replaced, How can I provide the system a static IP? Does an Elastic IP stick to such instances that are replaced?

Update: Spot Details added

[image]

Comment: There are many ways you can setup your spot. You haven't provided any info on its setting. Are you using persistent spot, capacity rebalancing? How did you exactly create your instance?

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I've updated with the spot details. Can you check and help me out with this?